# Probability of rolling a straight in Yahtzee

Tags: probability, dice, conditional-probability

I am trying to compute a *very specific* probability given a game of Yahtzee.

Here are the rules:

- There are 5 fair, 5-sided dice with equal probability of rolling each number.
- You have 3 rolls to obtain a straight [1,2,3,4,5].
- Per Yahtzee rules, you can choose which dice to reroll, in order to obtain a straight. (ie, if on roll 1 you get [1,2,3,3,4], you can keep [1,2,3,4] and reroll 1 dice)
- **Your first roll must have a 3 of a kind (ie: [1,2,3,3,3] or [1,1,3,3,3]**
- First rolls with 4 of a kind, 5 of a kind, or a perfect straight **DO NOT** count (ie: [3,3,3,3,4])

I am trying to write this in terms of mathematic notation. My intuition is telling me that this is a conditional probability, where

$P(C)$ = probability that we get a 3 of a kind on roll 1

$P(A)$ = probability that we roll a straight in 3 rolls

$P(A \mid C)$ = probability that we roll a straight in 3 rolls, given we get a 3 of a kind on roll 1

$$P(A \mid C) = \frac{P(A {\cap} C)}{P(C)}$$

I am worried my intuition is incorrect. I ran simulations (verified correct, 20000 trials) that say the probability of getting 3 of a kind on the first roll is roughly 20.06%, and the probability of getting a straight, given you get 3 of a kind on the first roll, is roughly 4.34%.

However, plugging in these values to my conditional probability results in:

$$P(A \mid C) = \frac{0.0434}{0.2006} = 0.2163$$

I am confused - isn't $P(A \mid C)$ the probability of getting a straight in 3 rolls, given you roll a 3 of a kind on the first try?

Any guidance would be very helpful - I wrote code simulations first, and now need to write a general verification of my result (0.0434) by hand.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are confusing $P(A \cap C)$ and $P(A | C)$ in the calculation after your simulation. The numerator ($P(A \cap C)$) shouldn't be $0.0434$, but the number of times you got $A$ **and** $C$, divided by the total amount of simulations. The result should then be $0.0434$.

For the mathematical calculation of this probability, you should be more precise on how we choose which dice to reroll after each round.

Comment: @TkiDeneb Thank you - this helped clear some stuff up. Is it right to say that this is question is asking a conditional probability? Do you think that testing for the probability of A (get a straight) given C (get 3 of a kind on first roll) is the right verbal terminology?

Comment: That depends on what you want.

If you are looking for the probability to get $3$ of a kind in the first roll and then a straight in **any attempt**, you want $P(A \cap C)$. (Imagine placing yourself **before** the first roll.)

If you are looking for the probability to get a straight after you have **already gotten** $3$ of a kind, then you want $P(A \mid C)$. (Imagine placing yourself **after** a first roll that had $3$ of a kind.)